# What does 'For long, in need' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase "For long, in need" connote?

Comment: Without context, it doesn't really mean *anything* (or it could have too many possible meanings, depending on how you look at things).

Comment: It isn't a sentence. It doesn't have a verb or a subject. Please give the full context.

Comment: "A friend, for long in need" as pay off line of a brand.

Comment: "Pay off line of a brand" makes no sense, so that's no help.

Comment: 'A friend in need ...' means 'A friend who remains true even when you ask a lot of them (overtly or tacitly) ...', not 'A friend who has needs ...'.

Answer (score 2):

The only quote I could find online was from page 194 of *Product Development and Management* edited by Raghubir Dayal, Peter Zachariah, Kireet Rajpal and published by Mittal Publications, a New Delhi publisher.

> The ball pen was a new innovation, **for long in need**; a pen that need
>   no refilling, no messing about of cloth or fingers, no broken ink
>   bottles;....

I expect that there may have been little editing by native speakers of BrE or AmE.  "New innovation" is redundant.  The use of semicolons is nonstandard punctuation. "Messing about of cloth" is an odd locution, as is "for long in need."  From the context, it's clear the latter means "long-needed" or "a long time in coming."

Comment: I agree 100%. The sentence is poorly written.